# Missing templates using PHPStorm when using Craft 3

Tags: craft3

Following code show a warning "template not found" in PHPStorm:

`{% extends '_layout' %}`.

When adding .twig this warning dissapears, but I'd like to keep extends and includes filetype agnostic.

What I've tried so far:

1. Installing the [Symfony plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219-symfony-plugin) and enabling Twig support.
2. Adding the templates folder as a Twig directory, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148786/missing-twig-template-in-phpstorm-with-symfony-plugin/46971447?noredirect=1#comment98087639_46971447).
3. Invalidate PHPStorm cache and restart.

Is there a way to fix this? Or should I use `{% extends '_layout.twig' %}`?

Using PHPStorm 2019.1

Comment: I've been working with Craft and PHP Storm for about 6 years, this is definitely a new issue with the IDE, maybe something in the `2019.1` release. I would be interested to know how to get round this too as I don't like to include files with extensions either.

Comment: You thinking it's a bug in PhpStorm? Not seeing anything already filed in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI?q=twig%20extension%20template%20not%20found&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was probably a bug in PHPStorm 2019.1.

Currently using 2019.1.2 and the warning disappeared.